# Calcular distância entre 2 pontos no Google maps

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysqli

Não tenho muita experiência com javascript e não tenho ideia de como pegar o resultado desse script e passar para um campo `<input text>`.
Esse script calcula a distância e o tempo entre dois pontos. Então queria pegar o tempo e a distância e então salvá-lo em um banco de dados.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Calcular distancia entre cidades (mapas e rotas)</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Parâmetro sensor é utilizado somente em dispositivos com GPS -->
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CalculaDistancia() {
        $('#litResultado').html('Aguarde...');
        //Instanciar o DistanceMatrixService
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        //executar o DistanceMatrixService
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
          {
              //Origem
              origins: [$("#txtOrigem").val()],
              //Destino
              destinations: [$("#txtDestino").val()],
              //Modo (DRIVING | WALKING | BICYCLING)
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
              //Sistema de medida (METRIC | IMPERIAL)
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
              //Vai chamar o callback
          }, callback);
    }
    //Tratar o retorno do DistanceMatrixService
    function callback(response, status) {
        //Verificar o Status
        if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK)
            //Se o status não for "OK"
            $('#litResultado').html(status);
        else {
            //Se o status for OK
            //Endereço de origem = response.originAddresses
            //Endereço de destino = response.destinationAddresses
            //Distância = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text
            //Duração = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
            var x = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
            $('#litResultado').html("<strong>Origem</strong>: " +    
 response.originAddresses +
                "<br /><strong>Destino:</strong> " + response.destinationAddresses +
                "<br /><strong>Distância</strong>: " +  
 response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text +
                " <br /><strong>Duração</strong>: " + 
 response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
                );
            //Atualizar o mapa
            $("#map").attr("src", "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + 
    response.originAddresses + "&daddr=" + response.destinationAddresses +  
    "&output=embed");
        }
    }
   </script>

   <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
       <label for="txtOrigem"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de origem</strong></label>
       <input type="text" id="txtOrigem" class="field" style="width: 400px" />
       <label for="txtDestino"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de destino</strong></label>
       <input type="text" style="width: 400px" class="field" id="txtDestino" />
       <input type="button" value="Calcular dist&acirc;ncia"  onclick="CalculaDistancia()" class="btnNew" />
  <div><span id="litResultado">&nbsp;</span></div>

  <!------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <input type="text" value="<? Variavel distancia?>"  
    <input type="text" value="<? Variavel tempo?>"  
  <!------------------------------------------------------------------->

 <div style="padding: 10px 0 0; clear: both">
    <iframe width="750" scrolling="no" height="350" frameborder="0" id="map" 
  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=são 
 paulo&daddr=rio de janeiro&output=embed"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Só dando uma olhada por cima, eu vi que há um elemento `<table>` não-fechado que não contém linhas e colunas dentro dele. Isso está certo? Além disso, o seu HTML não está completo, uma vez que não tem o `</body>` e nem o `</html>`.

Comment: Mais Ta funcionando sim. Na verdade ele não vai ter nem tabela

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Acho que consegui resolver.

Primeiro eu corrigi os problemas com a HTML mal formada: Está faltando o `</body>` e o `</html>` no final, que acrescentei. Você tem um elemento `<table>` sobrando que é inútil, e eu o removi. Você está quebrando linha dentro do atributo `src` do `<iframe>` e isso é ruim,  e eu não quebrei linha ali. Além disso, eu acrescentei o `<!DOCTYPE html>` e o `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Por fim, dei um jeito em alguns escapes que estavam faltando (`â` para `&acirc;` e `ã` para `&atilde;`).

Depois, eu acrescentei os campos onde o resultado será colocado. Também separei-os dos campos onde a pesquisa é realizada. Fiz os campos do resultado serem somente-leitura para garantir que o resultado deles de fato venha do Google (no entanto, não confie nisso se você for disponibilizar para o público em geral). Coloquei todos eles dentro de um `<form>` com um botão *submit* para poder enviar ao servidor posteriormente:

> EDIT: Em 11/06/2018, mais de três anos depois da data em que esta pergunta e esta resposta foram postadas, o Google mudou o formato da API. Até então, era possível utilizar a API gratuitamente sem necessitar de uma API Key. Com a mudança, torna-se necessário o uso de uma API Key, que só pode ser ativada com um cartão de crédito. Veja mais [neste link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key?hl=pt-br), [nesta página](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?hl=pt-br) e [aqui](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/8gkmeo/starting_google_maps_platform_arrives_with/). Nos códigos que se segue, substitua o `API_KEY_AQUI` pelo valor do seu API Key. E para usar o seu API Key, você deverá ativá-lo.

```html
    <form action="http://www.example.com/url" method="post">
      <div><span>Pesquisa:</span></div>
      <label for="txtOrigem"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de origem</strong></label>
      <input name="pesquisaOrigem" type="text" id="txtOrigem" class="field" style="width: 400px" value="S&atilde;o Paulo" />
      <label for="txtDestino"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de destino</strong></label>
      <input name="pesquisaDestino" type="text" id="txtDestino" class="field" style="width: 400px" value="Rio de Janeiro" />
      <input type="button" value="Calcular dist&acirc;ncia" onclick="CalculaDistancia()" class="btnNew" />
      <div><span id="litResultado">&nbsp;</span></div>

      <div><span>Resposta:</span></div>
      <label for="txtOrigemResultado"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de origem</strong></label>
      <input name="resultadoOrigem" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="txtOrigemResultado" class="field" style="width: 400px" value="" />
      <label for="txtDestinoResultado"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de destino</strong></label>
      <input name="resultadoDestino" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="txtDestinoResultado" class="field" style="width: 400px" value="" />
      <br />
      <label for="txtDistancia"><strong>Dist&acirc;ncia</strong></label>
      <input name="distancia" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="txtDistancia" value="" /> 
      <label for="txtTempo"><strong>Tempo</strong></label>
      <input name="tempo" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="txtTempo" value="" />
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar para o servidor" />
    </form>
```

Arrumei o javascript para preencher estes campos no callback. Já aproveitei para retirar o "aguarde" quando a resposta chegar e também traduzi o tempo para o português.

```js
      // Tratar o retorno do DistanceMatrixService
      function callback(response, status) {
        // Verificar o status.
        if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) { // Se o status não for "OK".
            $("#litResultado").html(status);
        } else { // Se o status for "OK".
            $("#litResultado").html("&nbsp;"); // Remove o "aguarde".

            // Popula os campos.
            $("#txtOrigemResultado").val(response.originAddresses);
            $("#txtDestinoResultado").val(response.destinationAddresses);
            $("#txtDistancia").val(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
            var tempo = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
            tempo = tempo.replace("day", "dia").replace("hour", "hora").replace("min", "minuto");
            $("#txtTempo").val(tempo);

            //Atualizar o mapa.
            $("#map").attr("src", "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + response.originAddresses + "&daddr=" + response.destinationAddresses + "&output=embed&key=API_KEY_AQUI");
        }
      }
```

Eis o HTML completo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calcular dist&acirc;ncia entre cidades (mapas e rotas)</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Parâmetro sensor é utilizado somente em dispositivos com GPS -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=API_KEY_AQUI"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function CalculaDistancia() {
        $('#litResultado').html('Aguarde...');
        // Instancia o DistanceMatrixService.
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        // Executa o DistanceMatrixService.
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [$("#txtOrigem").val()], // Origem
            destinations: [$("#txtDestino").val()], // Destino
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING, // Modo (DRIVING | WALKING | BICYCLING)
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC // Sistema de medida (METRIC | IMPERIAL)
        }, callback); // Vai chamar o callback
      }

      // Tratar o retorno do DistanceMatrixService
      function callback(response, status) {
        // Verificar o status.
        if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) { // Se o status não for "OK".
            $("#litResultado").html(status);
        } else { // Se o status for "OK".
            $("#litResultado").html("&nbsp;"); // Remove o "aguarde".

            // Popula os campos.
            $("#txtOrigemResultado").val(response.originAddresses);
            $("#txtDestinoResultado").val(response.destinationAddresses);
            $("#txtDistancia").val(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
            var tempo = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
            tempo = tempo.replace("day", "dia").replace("hour", "hora").replace("min", "minuto");
            $("#txtTempo").val(tempo);

            //Atualizar o mapa.
            $("#map").attr("src", "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + response.originAddresses + "&daddr=" + response.destinationAddresses + "&output=embed&key=API_KEY_AQUI");
        }
      }
    </script>

    <form action="http://www.example.com/url" method="post">
      <div><span>Pesquisa:</span></div>
      <label for="txtOrigem"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de origem</strong></label>
      <input name="pesquisaOrigem" type="text" id="txtOrigem" class="field" style="width: 400px" value="S&atilde;o Paulo" />
      <label for="txtDestino"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de destino</strong></label>
      <input name="pesquisaDestino" type="text" id="txtDestino" class="field" style="width: 400px" value="Rio de Janeiro" />
      <input type="button" value="Calcular dist&acirc;ncia" onclick="CalculaDistancia()" class="btnNew" />
      <div><span id="litResultado">&nbsp;</span></div>

      <div><span>Resposta:</span></div>
      <label for="txtOrigemResultado"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de origem</strong></label>
      <input name="resultadoOrigem" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="txtOrigemResultado" class="field" style="width: 400px" value="" />
      <label for="txtDestinoResultado"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de destino</strong></label>
      <input name="resultadoDestino" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="txtDestinoResultado" class="field" style="width: 400px" value="" />
      <br />
      <label for="txtDistancia"><strong>Dist&acirc;ncia</strong></label>
      <input name="distancia" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="txtDistancia" value="" /> 
      <label for="txtTempo"><strong>Tempo</strong></label>
      <input name="tempo" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="txtTempo" value="" />
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar para o servidor" />
    </form>

    <div style="padding: 10px 0 0; clear: both">
      <iframe width="750" scrolling="no" height="350" frameborder="0" id="map" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=S&atilde;o Paulo&daddr=Rio de Janeiro&output=embed"></iframe>
    </div>
  </head>
</html>
```

Para usar, você deve proceder assim:

1. Você escolhe os locais desejados e os preenche nos campos de pesquisa.
2. Clique no botão "Calcular distância".
3. O Google trará o resultado.
4. O javascript preencherá os campos do formulário com os resultados.
5. Você clica no botão "Enviar para o servidor" e os dados do formulário serão enviados ao servidor.

No servidor, você vai receber uma requisição POST contendo os seguintes campos de formulário: `pesquisaOrigem`, `pesquisaDestino`, `resultadoOrigem`, `resultadoDestino`, `distancia` e `tempo`. O significado de cada um deles é óbvio. A URL responsável por receber este serviço deverá ser configurada no seu servidor e o campo `action` do seu `<form>` no HTML deve coincidir com ela.

Se preferir, você pode fazer com que a resposta OK do Google já submeta o resultado via AJAX para o seu servidor automaticamente. Ou então você pode querer colocar alguma lógica de validação mais complexa no seu botão "Enviar para o servidor". Neste caso, se você tiver alguma dúvida de como fazer isso, já fica para o escopo de uma outra pergunta, mas nada te impede de adaptar este processo como lhe convier.

Já no servidor, você executará um *prepared statement* com uma instrução SQL mais ou menos assim:

```sql
INSERT INTO Distancias (pesquisaOrigem, pesquisaDestino, resultadoOrigem, resultadoDestino, distancia, tempo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Ou simplesmente assim:

```sql
INSERT INTO Distancias (origem, destino, distancia, tempo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

E então é só preencher os parâmetros do seu *prepared statement* com os dados recebidos do formulário. No entanto, antes de fazê-lo, talvez você queira pré-processá-los para converter todos os tempos em minutos, converter todas as distâncias em valores numéricos (eliminando o sufixo `" km"`), e talvez dando alguma arrumada na origem e no destino caso queira eliminar informações que você julgue desnecessárias como número de rua, CEP, diferenças entre maiúsculas/minúsculas, ou o que você quiser.

Comment: muito bom o que vi aqui, tive a resposta que procurava!

Comment: eu estou usando seu código em um sistema, mas estou com um problema, está retornando um erro após alguns testes que fiz, esperei 10 min e o erro continua: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT