# Sistema de rotas em PHP utilizando a API do Google Maps

Tags: php, xml, google-maps

Estou terminando um sistema em PHP, onde o cliente perguntou se tem como, gerar uma rota entre empresas, e gerar a mais curta, por exemplo, ele tem 50 empresas cadastradas no banco de dados, com endereço e tudo mais, ele quer, selecionar por exemplo 10 dessas empresas para fazer entregas, o que ele me perguntou foi: Consigo selecionar as 10 empresas, e o sistema resgatar os endereços, e ele (com auxilio da API da google) calcular a rota mais curta entre esses 10 pontos? eu lhe respondi "boa pergunta" haha.

Brincadeiras a parte, nunca trabalhei com a API do Google Maps, será que alguém tem alguma dica, ou auxilio? E a pergunta que não quer calar, tem como passar esses 10 endereços no exemplo do cliente por XML(ou outro tipo) para o Google Maps calcular a rota mais curta e me mostrar essa rota?

Obrigado a todos, como diz o ditado perguntar não ofende!

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49505/132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso você pode usar a [**API da Matriz de distâncias do Google**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?hl=pt-br) para obter a distância e tempo de deslocamento para uma matriz de origens e destinos. Esse serviço não retorna informações detalhadas do trajeto.

A API da Matriz de distâncias tem o seguinte formato:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/output?parameters
```

O protocolo HTTPS é recomendado para aplicativos que incluem nas solicitações dados confidenciais do usuário, como, por exemplo, sua localização:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/output?parameters
```

Em ambos os casos, *output* pode ser em JSON ou XML.

**Parâmetros obrigatórios**

- **origins**: Um ou mais endereços e/ou valores textuais de latitude/longitude, separados pelo caractere de barra vertical (|), a partir dos quais a distância e o tempo são calculados. Se você informa um endereço como uma sequência, o serviço geocodifica a sequência e a converte em uma coordenada de latitude/longitude para calcular as rotas. Se você informar coordenadas, verifique se não existe espaço entre os valores de latitude e longitude.

  ```
  origins=Bobcaygeon+ON|41.43206,-81.38992
  ```
- **destinations**: Um ou mais endereços e/ou valores textuais de latitude/longitude, separados pelo caractere de barra vertical (|), para os quais a distância e o tempo são calculados. Se você informa um endereço como uma sequência, o serviço geocodifica a sequência e a converte em uma coordenada de latitude/longitude para calcular as rotas. Se você informar coordenadas, verifique se não existe espaço entre os valores de latitude e longitude.

  ```
  destinations=Darling+Harbour+NSW+Australia|24+Sussex+Drive+Ottawa+ON|Capitola+CA
  ```
- **sensor**: Indica se seu aplicativo está usando um sensor (por exemplo, um localizador GPS) para determinar a localização do usuário. Este valor deve ser *true* ou *false*.

**Parâmetros opcionais**

- **mode**: Especifica qual meio de transporte usar ao calcular rotas. Os valores válidos são:

  - **driving (padrão)**: Indica rotas de trânsito padrão usando a rede rodoviária.
  - **walking**: Solicita rotas a pé por faixas de pedestre e calçadas (onde disponíveis).
  - **bicycling**: Solicita rotas de bicicleta em ciclovias e ruas preferidas (**atualmente, disponível apenas nos EUA e em algumas cidades do Canadá**).
  - **language**: O idioma em que os resultados devem ser retornados. Consulte a [lista de idiomas de domínio suportados](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=pt-br#languagesupport). A lista de idiomas suportados é atualizada com frequência; portanto, ela não é definitiva.
  - **avoid**: Introduz restrições no trajeto. Os valores válidos são especificados na seção [Restrições](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?hl=pt-br#Restrictions) deste documento. Só é possível especificar uma restrição.
  - **units**: Especifica o sistema de unidades a ser usado ao expressar distância como texto. Consulte a seção [Sistemas](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?hl=pt-br#unit_systems) de unidades deste documento para obter mais informações.

As informações de trajeto podem ser obtidas informando-se a origem e o destino únicos desejados para a [**Google Directions API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=pt-br).

Comment: Wooow muito obrigado amigo. Mais esclarecedor impossível. Grande abraço