# Gerador de rotas

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps, maps

Tenho um mapa com pontos pré definidos, porem gostaria de saber se tem como colocar um gerador de rota como no "maps" para  que a pessoa digite o seu endereço e clique em um dos pontos do mapa e gere endereço, distancia e todo o resto?

Comment: Como assim não é claro o que ele está perguntando? Ele quer saber [como criar rotas](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=pt-br) a partir de um endereço até um ponto que o usuário escolher.

Comment: não, quero saber como deixar o usuario botar seu endereço e gerar uma rota mas em um mapa com pontos já pré definidos

Comment: Olá André. Você poderia especificar um pouco melhor seus problema para que a comunidade tente lhe ajudar? Sugiro dar mais detalhes sobre o seu mapa (é um GoogleMap?), você quer criar um algoritmo de rotas ou quer saber se o GoogleMaps possui um disponível pra você? O que as tags Javascript e html5 têm a ver com o problema? Tudo isso pode ajudar a esclarecer o problema. Abraço.

Comment: Então eu criei uma mapa no MYmaps e nele eu especifiquei vários marcadores, cada marcador corresponde a uma unidade de uma empresa, esse mapa eu quero expor no site da empresa para que o interessado em achar coloque seu endereço e clique diretamente em um dos marcadores para que se gere o trajeto até o ponto desejado.

Comment: Exemplo quando tu abre o google maps tem um campo para você por seu endereço e onde deseja ir ESSE CAMPO é o que eu quero por NO MEU MAPA para O USUARIO poder colocar seu endereço e E GERAR A ROTA ate o ponto mais próximo. As tags HTM e javascript estão por que ate agora as unicas soluções que eu achei envolvem programar e eu queria saber se não existe algo pronto do próprio google.

Comment: O que eu quero é incorporar a "ferramenta de Rotas" no mapa que eu criei.

Comment: Essa ferramenta parece muito limitada. Se você criar um mapa por programação, aí as possibilidades são mais amplas. Talvez isto te ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49657/sistema-de-rotas-em-php-utilizando-a-api-do-google-maps